# Defining functions in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, dynamic

How do define my own functions in Mathematica that I can interact with? For example, in C++ I can write

```
int exp (int x, int y) {
    return (x*y)
}
int main(){
    int a, b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    int c = exp (a,b);
    cout << c;
}
```

For Mathematica I tried this but it didn't work.

```
With[
 {exp[x_, y_] := x^y,
  Dynamic[c := exp[a, b]]},
 InputField[Dynamic[a]]
 InputField[Dynamic[b]]
 Dynamic[c]
 ]
```

Comment: Just get rid of the `With`, and put the function definition on its own line.

Comment: [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [Defining functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Comment: Speaking in C terms, `With` can only do assignments, but not declarations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's MMA equivalent:

```
exp[x_Integer,y_Integer]:=x y;

main[]:=Module[{a,b,c}
, a = Input["a"]
; b = Input["b"]
; c = exp[a,b]
]
```

in general, in the specific case you can go even further:

```
main[]:= Input[] Input[]
```

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RequestingInput.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I was working in Mathematica's notebook environment and not in its command line environment, I would make use of the GUI elements available to me and implement your C++ code this way:

```
exp[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^y

DynamicModule[{a = 10, b = 2},
  Panel @ Grid[
    {{"x   ", InputField[Dynamic[a], Alignment -> Right]},
     {"y   ", InputField[Dynamic[b], Alignment -> Right]},
     {x^y, Framed[Dynamic[exp[a, b]], 
             Alignment -> Right, Background -> White, ImageSize -> 183]}},
    Alignment -> Left]]
```

which would produce a GUI panel like so:

[image: panel]

The point of this post is to show you how to implement something equivalent  to your C++ `main` function in a notebook. Actually, the `DynamicModule` I show above is much more capable and convenient to use than `main`.